# The determinant of skew-symmetric matrix of even order is a square as a polynomial in matrix elements

Tags: matrices, polynomials, determinant

Help me, please, to  solve this task:
Prove that the determinant of skew-symmetric matrix of even order have a full square as a polynomial in matrix elements

Comment: The proof is not short... [This article](http://dx.doi.org/10.1017/S0013091500018423) has it.

Comment: @user147263 I think the paper presumed that $V$ is invertible in the inductive step, which may be too restrictive.